# How to Install Openyxl

Tags: pip

When I try to install `openyxl` with `pip install openyxl` in Command Prompt it gives me the following errors:

```
ERROR: Could not find a version that satisfies the requirement openyxl (from versions: none)
ERROR: No matching distribution found for openyxl
```

This is what I see in the command prompt:

[image: This is what I see in command prompt]

Comment: Hi, welcome to Stack Overflow. I think you mean to install `openpyxl` rather than `openyxl`. Try running `pip install openpyxl` and see if that works.

Answer (score 1):

Try this.

```
pip install openpyxl
```

The package name is "openpyxl"

Comment: Damn it! I had been struggling the entire afternoon trying to solve it and it was just a name issue after all. Thanks!